# ArraySort using anonymous comparator gives error

Tags: java, sorting, search, binary, comparator

Error : javac says its not applicable, I don't know why?

plz help **whats the concept that I am missing here**.

```
>> ROOT: }     Search_In_2D_Matrix.java:50: error: no suitable method found for sort(int[],<anonymous Comparator<Integer>>)
            Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
                  ^
        method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
          (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
            equality constraints: int
            upper bounds: Integer,Object)
        method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
          (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
            (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
      where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
        T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
        T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
    Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
    1 error
```

//--------------------------------------------------

```
public static void name() {
    int arr[] = new int[] { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    Arrays.binarySearch(arr, -1, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    });

    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return a.intValue() - b.intValue();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `Integer` and `int` are not the same thing.

Comment: Your problem is that `int` raw type does not extends `Integer`.

Comment: @MickaëlB `int` isn't a raw type. It's a primitive. It extends *nothing*.

Comment: In `Arrays.sort(...)`, the type of the array has to extends the type defined in the `Comparator` : `Comparator<? super T#1>`

Comment: @Kayaman That's exactly my point.

Comment: Wouldn't matter. `Arrays.sort( int[] )` doesn't even accept a comparator. Only `Arrays.sort( T[] , Comparator<? super T)` does, but only works for Objects.

Comment: @MickaëlB Don't use the words "raw type" when referring to primitives. That's just wrong.

Comment: @Kayaman Fair enough.

Comment: Why do you want to provide your own Comparator anyway?

Comment: `arr = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sort(comparator).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();`

Comment: so what if I want to do binary search on a primitive int[] which is sorted in decreasing order. so for that would I first need to sort it in increasing order and then do the binary search. as mentioned comparator will be use less here

Answer (score 2):

The methods that take a `Comparator` are for object arrays. With primitive arrays you don't have that option.

You can turn your `int[]` into `Integer[]` and then it will work.

Comment: This is what actually meant but I probably explained it badly.

Comment: @Kayaman so if I want to do binary search on a primitive int[] which is sorted in decreasing order. so for that would I first need to sort it in increasing order and then do the binary search. as you have mentioned comparator will be use less

Comment: @user6202188 yes, that's the way to go. The `binarySearch` method expects "normal" sorting, i.e. ascending, and there's no general comparator like functionality for primitives, since they have a natural order.